# How to kill query stuck in loop

Tags: mysql, loops, kill

I have a query running in mySQL (through myAdminPHP) that is stuck in an infinite loop and seems to be continually executing.

I can't kill the specific process because the process ID is constantly incrementing.

How do I stop this query from running?

[image]

Comment: That query looks like it is you, right now, running the query that asks the server for the list of running queries.

Comment: So this query about the list of running queries is always running in a MySql server? Its normal?.  Because I didn't make that query. That screen is the result of clicking the PROCESSLIST table.My doubts come up from the fact that the server says: This server has been active during 0 days 10 hours and 50 minutes. So I thougth this wasnt normal. When I run the "show status like 'Threads%'" query, the  results is  Value Threads_cached 0
Threads_connected 7
Threads_created 51419
Threads_running 1

Comment: You did make that query. *"That screen is the result of clicking the PROCESSLIST table."* Right, but clicking a table actually runs a query. The query you see isn't running all the time -- it's running *because* you clicked the processlist table -- it's the query gathering the info you just asked for.  `SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.PROCESSLIST WHERE ID != CONNECTION_ID();` will exclude your own query from showing in the list. Or (for illustration purposes) change `!=` to `=` to see *only* your own. (The `CONNECTION_ID()` function always returns the id of the thread that invoked it: yours.)